Code autocompletion not working properly for Jetpack Compose in Android Studio
I'm having problems with code completion on Jetpack compose. When I start typing and a suggestion appears, I press tab to input the suggestion and the formatting goes super messed up. This is quite frustrating. I get parameters with "a" as value for no reason, and the caret moves to unexpected places, and sometimes letters are deleted...
See GIF below showing what happens:

Anyone know what cold be causing this? Have I got a weird setting enabled or something?

Do you have any custom plugins installed?

i have the same problem, did you find a solution?
